# How should we deal with two questions that are different, but would be duplicates if worded well?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

On SpaceEx.SE, we have two questions that have fundamentally the same answer, but are asked in slightly different ways. Technically speaking, the questions are different because of the way they are worded, however if they were both worded correctly they would be duplicates. As it is neither is worded particularly well according to the technical terminology used, though one is slightly better.

Here are the two questions:

[Is there any reason in sending the space probes along the plane of our solar system instead perpendicular to the plane of our solar system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/is-there-any-reason-in-sending-the-space-probes-along-the-plane-of-our-solar-sys)

[Would leaving the ecliptic plane offer any benefit to interstellar travel?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/834/would-leaving-the-ecliptic-plane-offer-any-benefit-to-interstellar-travel)

Comment: The particular technical issue here is confusion about plane transfer in space travel and the definition of different planes. The invariant plane is the plane of the solar system. The ecliptic plane is the plane of Earth's orbit. All interplanetary and interstellar missions involve plane transfer, so they travel at some inclination from these planes.

Comment: Well, each has pretty completely different answers, and neither answer seems like it would fit if posted to the other question.  Based on that, I'd say the're not duplicates.

Comment: @Servy Allowing for variance in the way the technical terms are used/abused the answers *are* interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

You close the worst worded in duplicate of the slightly best worded (or the one with best answers or w/e you decide is the best option for users coming to the site).

Having different wording is not a bad thing, because it makes more ways to find the question.

Having a question close as a duplicates only means that by finding one you will also find the other, which is nice because you will just find the answer you are looking for easily.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that these questions are duplicates as they are right now, or at least so close to each other that it seems the answers for one would be reasonable answers for the other. They could be closed as duplicates as is, without re-wording.

Comment: So the more recent one should be closed even though it is more accurately worded? (It allows for some inclination from the plane.)

Comment: @called2voyage You can close whichever you want as a duplicate of whichever you want, if you think they really are duplicates.  There is no need to close the newer one.